# Java 8 Date API - Getting week of month throws UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: DayOfWeek

Tags: java, kotlin, date

I am trying to get the week of the current month like so:

```
YearMonth
    .from(Instant.now().atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")))
    .get(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfMonth())
```

But this throws

> java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: DayOfWeek

I can't seem to work out why I'm getting this exception, because I'm not doing anything with `DayOfWeek`. Any ideas?

Comment: By the way, there is a constant defined for UTC: [`ZoneOffset.UTC`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't get the week of the current month using `YearMonth`. It only has **year** and **month**. Change

```
YearMonth
    .from(Instant.now().atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")))
    .get(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfMonth())
```

to

```
LocalDate
    .from(Instant.now().atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")))
    .get(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfMonth())
```

And I get

```
1
```